# Computing inverse two-sided Laplace transform symbolically

Tags: matlab, inverse, laplace-transform, symbolic-computation

How can I compute the inverse two-sided Laplace transform symbolically?

I know MATLAB has ilaplace[1], but that's just for a one-sided transform.

[1] http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ilaplace.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot calculate inverse two-sided Laplace transform by MATLAB. Because there are at least two reasons:

$1.$ MATLAB has not defined the functions for calculating inverse two-sided Laplace transform.

$2.$ Inverse one-sided Laplace transform is unique, but inverse two-sided Laplace transform is not unique. The reasons are explained in [$\mathcal{B}^{-1}_{s\to x}\{e^{as^2+bs}\}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to x}\{e^{as^2+bs}\}$ , where $a\neq0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169275) .