# About the inverse laplace transform of sinc function

Tags: laplace-transform, contour-integration

How to calculate $\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to x}\{\text{sinc}(s)\}$ ?

Note: $\text{sinc}(s)=\dfrac{\sin s}{s}$ when $s\neq0$ .

Also note that $\lim\limits_{s\to\pm\infty}\dfrac{\sin s}{s}=0$ .

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd go about this.  The usual Bromwich contour won't work because sine does not converge on the outer arc contour.  I started to think about distribution functions of imaginary argument, but then I'm not even sure how that would work.

Comment: @Ron Gordon: In this question I want to know about $\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to x}\{\text{sinc}(s)\}$ , not $\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to x}\{\sin s\}$ !

Comment: @Ron Gordon: But for example according to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169275 I can easily get an example that $\mathcal{B}^{-1}_{s\to x}\{e^{as^2}\}=\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4a}}}{\sqrt{4a\pi}}$ when $a>0$ , which seems to show that the function converges at $\infty$ is not a must condition to make the inverse transform of the function exist.

Comment: Moreover, the difference between the bilateral laplace transform and the laplace transform are only one is for integrating from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and other one is for integrating from $0$ to $+\infty$ , I don't think the effects on their existance of their inverse transform really differ so large.