# Is it true that the Laplace Transform of a real function with compact support is always entire?

Tags: laplace-transform

Is it true that the Laplace Transform of a real function with compact support is always entire (entire = complex derivative exists on the entire complex plane)?

Comment: This seems to be very much in the spirit of the [Paley-Wiener theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem) Unfortunately I'm a little bit weak on this so perhaps someone else can comment further.

Comment: Of course, this is true. The Laplace transform coincides with the Fourier transform up to the multiple $i$ in the argument, see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform, and the Fourier transform of a distribution (not necessary a function) with compact support is an entire function, see W.Rudin's "Functional analysis", 7.23 (perhaps there is a more convenient source with the formulation of this result for functions, I don't know).

Comment: Yes, as @SergeiAkbarov says, this is some part of a Paley-Wiener theorem, which should be easily google-able. E.g., http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2012-13/paley-wiener.pdf

Comment: @Sergei Akbarov: Really? But Fourier transform integrates from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ while Laplace transform integrates from $0$ to $\infty$ , so the Laplace transform should not only just coincides with the Fourier transform up to the multiple $i$ in the argument.

Comment: @paul garrett: But http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2012-13/paley-wiener.pdf only bases on the Fourier transform but not on the Laplace transform, the cases of the Fourier transform may not applicable on the cases of the Laplace transform.

Comment: @doraemonpaul: one can treat the Laplace transform as an integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ of a function which vanish everywhere on the left half-line of $\mathbb R$. Then the difference with the Fourier transform will be only in $i$ in the argument.

Comment: @doraemonpaul, for functions with compact support, the "i" in the exponent of Fourier or Laplace transform hardly matters, with regard to the qualitative question of entire-ness of the output of the transform.

Answer (score 3):

One should assume that the real function in question is integrable, otherwise the Laplace transform isn't defined at $\lambda=0$. Here is a more general statement.

**Claim**. Suppose $(\Omega, \mu)$ is a finite measure space and for every $\omega\in\Omega$ we have an entire function $f_\omega$. Suppose further that the family $\{f_\omega\}$ is uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $\mathbb C$. Then the function
$$F(z)=\int_\Omega f_\omega(z)\,d\mu(\omega) \tag1$$ 
is entire.

*Proof*. The integral (1) converges for all $z\in\mathbb C$, being the integral of a bounded function over a finite measure space. Since $f_\omega'$ are also uniformly bounded on compact subsets, the family $\{f_\omega\} $ is uniformly Lipschitz on compact subsets. This property  passes to $F$.

Let $T$ be a triangle in the complex plane. The integral $\int_T F(z)\,dz$ makes sense by the above, and can be computed with Fubini's theorem: 
$$
\int_T F(z)\,dz = \int_\Omega \left(\int_T f_\omega(z)\,d\mu(\omega)\right)dz  =\int_\Omega \left(\int_T f_\omega(z)\,dz\right) d\mu(\omega) =0
$$
By Morera's theorem, $F$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb C$. $\quad\Box$

In our situation, $\Omega$ is a finite interval in $\mathbb R$, $d\mu(\omega) = f(\omega)\,d\omega$, and $f_\omega(z) = e^{-\omega z} $. The assumptions in the claim are satisfied, and $F$ in (1) is the Laplace transform of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Really true?

But in fact most simple entire elementary functions their Laplace Transform are often unavoidable to have some singularities and not entire, and in fact finding the inverse Laplace Transform of entire functions are often much more difficult than that of the functions having some singularities. (e.g. headache in [$\mathcal{B}^{-1}_{s\to x}\{e^{as^2+bs}\}$ and $\mathcal{L}^{-1}_{s\to x}\{e^{as^2+bs}\}$ , where $a\neq0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169275))

Comment: I am afraid, I didn't understand this... Elementary functions have no compact support usually (however, this depends on the definition of elementary functions)... Is it possible that you missed this?