# How to restore a function from its Fourier transform on the imaginary axis?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a `very good' function on the real line; say, infinitely differentiable and compactly supported. We are given its Fourier transform on the imaginary axis: $$g(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(t)e^{xt}\,dt, \qquad x\in\mathbb R.$$ How can the values of $f$ be restored?

If we know an algorithm of finding $f(0)$, then the value $f(a)$ for any real $a$ can be found by the same algorithm applied to $e^{-iat}g$ in place of $g$. So it suffices to find an answer for a single point $a=0$.

The `bad' answer is, for instance, as follows: find all derivatives of $g$ at the origin, construct the corresponding entire function, take its values on the real axis and apply the inverse Fourier transform. I am interested in more direct procedures; although, unfortunately, I cannot formalize my criteria to consider an answer satisfactory.

Comment: Your function $g(x)$ is, up to a minus sign, the bilateral Laplace transform of $f(x)$. So you are looking for the inverse bilateral Laplace transform. A bit of caution is needed here; for example, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169275/mathcalb-1-s-to-x-eas2bs-and-mathcall-1-s-to-x-eas

Comment: Yes, thanks, I realized that this is the Laplace transform. In my case one can think that it is unilateral. From texts I have seen, one can get an impression that there is no good inversion formula; am I right?

Comment: I guess that depends what you consider a good inversion formula. In the unilateral case, one has http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform

Comment: I saw this, it seems I will not be able to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

As the Fourier transform of an infinitely differentiable and compactly supported function is analytic, you certainly can.

Comment: Can you suggest some formula or algorithm? My question is *how?*

Comment: This is purely theoric. The missing part is to find the entire function...

Comment: You needn't find the entire function, I would even prefer a direct formula.