Mellin Transform of a function evaluated on the imaginary axis.
I am interested in finding the Mellin transform of a complex function evaluated on the imaginary axis.
The Mellin transform is typically evaluated over the real numbers as follows:
$$ M[ f(x), s ]=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} f(x) dx $$
with known rules for handling real dilations by factoring out the dilation constant from the integral when dealing with the $x$-complex domain.
Given that the Mellin transform of $f(x)$ is known and f(x) extends to a complex function, can we obtain the Mellin transform for the imaginary domain, specifically for $f(ix)$?
This would be:
$$ M[ f(ix), s ]=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} f(ix) dx $$
However, this is no longer a standard Mellin transform, as the change of variables would alter the integration path to lie along the positive imaginary axis.
Is there an established formula or method to compute the Mellin transform after rotating the real axis to the imaginary axis?

This was partially addressed in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1011156/622884 and recall the correspondence rule between the Fourier and Mellin transforms given by the change of variable in the inverse Mellin transform definition: For $s=c+iw$ both $c$ and $w$ real numbers,
$$F[f(e^x)e^{cx}, w ] = M[f(x), c+ i w]$$
where $s=c+i w$ is the parameter of the Mellin transform and the line $\Re(s)=c$ belongs to some valid strip of integration.

Its the standard Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}_xg(x)=\int\limits_0^{\infty } g(x), x^{s-1} , dx$$ where $g(x)=f(i x)$. I'm not sure you can derive $\mathcal{M}_xg(x)$ from $\mathcal{M}_xf(x)$.

Indeed the aim of this question is to find the Mellin transform of $f(ix)$ in terms of the Mellin transform of $f(x)$.

The existence of $$\mathcal{M}_xf(x)=\int\limits_0^{\infty } f(x), x^{s-1} , dx$$ does not imply the existence of $$\mathcal{M}_xf(i x)=\int\limits_0^{\infty } f(i x), x^{s-1} , dx$$ or vice versa.

For example, for the function $$f(x)=e^{x^2}$$ one has $$\mathcal{M}_xf(i x)=\int_0^{\infty } e^{(i x)^2} x^{s-1} , dx=\int_0^{\infty } e^{-x^2} x^{s-1} , dx=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}{2},,\quad\Re(s)>0,$$ but does the Mellin transform $$\mathcal{M}_xf(x)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{x^2} x^{s-1} , dx$$ even converge for any value of $s$?

In the latter part of your question, it's not clear to me how $$\mathcal{M}_xf(i x)=\int\limits_0^{\infty } f(i x), x^{s-1} , dx$$ which seems to be the focus of your question is related to $$\mathcal{M}_x[f(x)](i s)=\int\limits_0^{\infty } f(x), x^{i s-1} , dx$$ or $$\mathcal{M}_x[f(x)](c+i s)=\int\limits_0^{\infty } f(x), x^{c+i s-1} , dx.$$

In the first equation, the Mellin transform of $f(ix)$ by definition, when we make the change of variable $ix\to x$ the set of integration rotates to the imaginary axis.
Example for $\Re(s)>1$ we can not calculate the Mellin transform of
$$f(y) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-iy}}. $$
but in this case the Mellin transform exists for $f(ix)$.
As you suggest, see $s=c-1 \ +iw$ and then switch $s$ and $w$ [both reals] in the complex coordinate sys to analize the case for $s=w -1 \ +ic$.
Another way to see it, is letting $w=0$ and continue the domain of $c$ to the complex in this strip...

...Then use the relation between Fourier and Mellin transforms:
$$F[f(e^x)e^{cx} , w ] = \ M[f(x) , c + iw] .$$
When $w=0$ we have an explicit Fourier transform evaluated on $c$ in the left, and this is where it connects with Fourier analysis on complex frequencies, which under the change of variable $x\to e^{it}$ locates its poles on the real axis of the $t$-complex plane.

I think I've got it. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4966852/622884
