# Inverse of Mellin transform with lower bound at $1$

Tags: laplace-transform, mellin-transform

I've seen two definitions of the Mellin transform: more commonly, $g$ is the Mellin transform of $f$ if $$g(s)=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}f(x)\; dx,$$ or secondly, and more rarely, defined by the same integral with the lower bound at $1$ in place of $0$. The second type seems to be easier to work with in some cases because it avoids a possible singularity at $0$. Now, the inverse Mellin transform is well defined for the first definition. However, for the second, what is the formula for the inverse?

If $$g(s)=\int_1^\infty x^{s-1} f(x)\; dx=\int_0^\infty e^{st}f(e^t)\;dt,$$ then applying the Laplace inversion formula we have $$f(s)=\frac 1{2\pi i}\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}s^{-x}g(x)\; dx$$ (for an appropriate constant $\gamma$) which is exactly the same as for the first definition of the Mellin transform. Clearly this is wrong; the two transforms are not identical. What is wrong here and what is the actual formula?

Comment: Remark: that's a pretty stupid alternative definition, since much of the point of the Mellin transform is preservation of $dx/x$ under scaling, which doesn't behave well with the bottom limit being $1$. Indeed, the alternative form is entirely equivalent to the Laplace transform.

Comment: @Chappers It occurs in analytic number theory (analysis of Dirichlet series), and probably in some other situations in which the preservation of $dx/x$ is not important.

Comment: My first guess is that the contour has ended up in a different place from usual, after all that substituting.

Comment: @Chappers I only see one substitution (of the dummy variable), and it's before applying Laplace inversion; how could the contour change?

Comment: Right, okay, I've got a better grip on what's going on now. Basically, read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169275/mathcalb-1-s-to-x-eas2bs-and-mathcall-1-s-to-x-eas), which is the version for the bilateral vs ordinary Laplace transforms (which as you note, is easily isomorphic to what you've got).

Comment: @Chappers Thanks, that's really helpful. Just to make sure I understand: the above inversion formula (with $\gamma$ real and to the right of all singularities) applies to the one-sides transform, and the two-sided transform converges in a different strip and therefore its inversion formula is the same, but with $\gamma$ now in this strip?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it. Then you have a choice of where to deform the contour to be able to invert the transform: this is the difference between, for example $ \int_0^1 x^{s-1} \, dx = s^{-1} $ and $ \int_1^{\infty} (-1)x^{s-1} \, dx = s^{-1} $: one converges for $\Re(s)>0$, the other for $\Re(s)<0$, but both to the same function. Choosing which one you want as the inverse of $s^{-1}$ is then a matter of where the contour starts, and which way you need to deform it to enclose the pole.